# Security issues when sending email through php

Tags: php, email

I created a file to test sending emails by php using the Mail.php library, however when I require-once "Mail.php", the server returns the following error: ModSecurity: Access allowed (phase 1 ).
The php file only has this single line of code. How do I solve this?

The code I want to make is this:

```
 require_once "Mail.php";
 
 $from = "Sandra Sender <sender@example.com>";
 $to = "Ramona Recipient <recipient@example.com>";
 $subject = "Hi!";
 $body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";
 
 $host = "mail.gdom.net";
 $username = "lfc hosted email";
 $password = "email password";
 
 $headers = array ('From' => $from,
   'To' => $to,
   'Subject' => $subject);
 $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
   array ('host' => $host,
     'auth' => true,
     'username' => $username,
     'password' => $password));
 
 $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);
 
 if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
   echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
 } else {
   echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
 }
```

Comment: Ask your system administrator why your script/request is blocked.

Comment: I already did it but they didn't know how to answer.

Comment: Well, it's them who configured it.

Comment: ok, obrigado pela ajuda. Vou falar com eles denovo.